# don't get the right size on small screen

Tags: css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I'm using bootstrap4 and [Stream UI Kit](https://htmlstream.com/preview/stream-ui-kit) for the user interface in my application but i don't get the right size of column on the small screen !!

example ! 
[image]

it's supposed to be one per line when we browse on mobile !! with col-md-4 you can check the [demo](https://tiwizi.org)

```
<!-- Campaigns Grid -->
    <section class="pt-11 pb-6 bg-light">
        <div class="container">


            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-5">
                <h2 class="h3 text-center">{{ trans('user.offers') }}</h2>
                <a href="{{ url('/campaigns?type=offer') }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">{{ trans('user.all') }}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                @foreach($offers as $demand)
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">

                        <div class="card h-100 border-0 shadow">
                            <a href="{{ url('/campaign/'.$demand->id) }}" class="d-block bg-gradient rounded-top">
                                <img class="card-img-top hover-fade-out" src="{{ url('upload/campaign/'. $demand->cover .'/') }}" alt="{{ $demand->title }}"  height="244">
                            </a>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <a href="{{ url('/campaign/'.$demand->id) }}">
                                    <h3>{{ $demand->title }}</h3>
                                </a>
                                <p>
                                    {!! str_limit(strip_tags($demand->content), 128) !!}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer d-flex">
                                @foreach($demand->categories as $category)
                                    @if(App::isLocale('ar')) <a href="{{ url('/category/'.$category->id) }} " class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mr-1" >{{ $category->title_ar }} </a>
                                    @elseif(App::isLocale('fr')) <a href="{{ url('/category/'.$category->id) }}" class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mr-1">{{ $category->title }}</a>
                                    @else <a href="{{ url('/category/'.$category->id) }}"  class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mr-1">{{ $category->title_en }}</a>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach


            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Campaigns Grid -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, col-md-4 along with all classes for devices.
Use this in one in line

class=“col-6 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4”

These classes themselves give responsive on all devices.
col - set mobile
col-md - set medium devices 
col-sm - small
col-lg - large
col-xl - extra large

They will manage automatically.

Comment: the same problem !! i steel get md-6 when screen min-width: 576px

Comment: You need to use both col-6 col-md-6

Comment: I did but steel don't get the result i want one per line ....

Comment: You canr try on the demo by add the with google chrome inspector !

Comment: For mobile you need to use col. “col-12 col-md-6“
col-12 will give you one line in mobile and col-md will work on other devices. Put both them together in class. Lemme know if still you stuck I will put your code with classes.